# How can I sum all numbers in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sum

Made up the following code:

```
import math    
def z(a,b,s):
    import math    
    elements = list()
    for i in range(a,b):
        elements.append(i**-s)
    return elements
    f = math.fsum(elements)
    print (f)
```

the problem is that I am getting back the list with "return elements" but not the "math.fsum(elements)
what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You might want to start with the basic Python tutorial. `return` statement immediately returns the value and rest of the statements will be ignored.

Comment: Why would you? You `return`ed from the function early; the function *ends* there.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed a few things, and made a few suggestions:

```
import math        # You should be aware that python has a builtin sum function
def z(a,b,s):
#import math   << There is no need to import the module twice, so I've commented it, meaning it won't execute
    elements = list()      # Unconventional, but it works - it's more common to just create a literal empty list like so:  elements = []
    for i in range(a,b):
        elements.append(i**-s)
    f = math.fsum(elements)
    return elements, f     # Here we're returning both your list AND the sum in a "tuple" (assuming you want to return both)
    # Note that once the return function executes, the interpreter exits the function, and nothing else in the function will be executed.

elements, f = z(5, 10, 3)   # Here we're calling the function, and "unpacking" the two things we returned from the tuple into two variables.

print f  # This will print out your sum.
```

Comment: FWIW, using [math.fsum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum) is probably preferable to using the built-in `sum()`, when you need the precision. (But I'd probably be using mpmath if I wanted to compute things related to zeta series...)

Comment: I would use a list comprehension: `elements = [i ** -s for i in range(a, b)]`

Comment: @PM2Ring yep, agreed - just wanted to make sure he knew about `sum`.

Comment: Brionius: Fair point. @Matthias: list comps are cool and neat, and I use them all the time, but they're not necessarily any faster than the equivalent simple `for` loop based code, even though the list comp lets you avoid the `.append()` call in the loop.

Comment: PM 2Ring@ Could you please advise further cause indeed I am trying some formulas on Rieman Zeta functions. Thanks

Comment: @DimitriosKokkotis: Take a look at the arbitrary-precision package, [mpmath](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/index.html). It lets you do all sorts of fancy maths to _huge_ precision. And it has the [zeta function](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/zeta.html) built-in.

Comment: Well it seems that I cannot use mpmath at all, getting errors in Pycharm